# How to check network reachability

Tags: iphone, reachability

I want check the reachability to a IP address on my LAN  from my iPhone app. 
does any one know how to check this.

Answer (score 1):

Attempt to connect to it using whatever service/protocol/port you intend to use.

Answer (score 0):

The `Reachability` is definitely the way to go with this & it's very simple to use too. Here's the code I use:

```
- (BOOL)_connectedToInternet
{
    Reachability*_currentReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];

    if (_currentReachability.currentReachabilityStatus == NotReachable)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

A simple Google search would have revealed this too though. Apple writes the developer documentation for a good reason...

Comment: Thanks Prypaiat, First thing i dont want to check internet connection.
Second I am already using Reachability class for checking reachability of an IP address. It returns always true. Even if i plug out that server. :(

Comment: Reachability can also be used to check for a specific IP, the code would be almost identical.

Comment: Yes. I do check for reach ability of certain IPs and that works too.

Comment: Look in the documentation! That's what it's for. If you did, you'd see that `reachabilityWithHostName:` exists as a method too.